# The word 'wilma'

Tags: meaning

A friend of mine told me that the word 'wilma' is an informal American word meaning 'an ugly woman'. I am really confused because I have looked up most American dictionaries and none of them gives such a meaning.Is there any native American speaker who ever used this word?

Comment: I'm a native American English speaker, and I've never encountered the word *wilma* used to describe an ugly woman. All it conjures up for me is Fred Flinstone's wife. Sounds to me like some slang local to a particular high school or some far-flung middle American county. If I get a chance to go to the library today, I'll check the DARE.

Comment: *Wilma* might or might not mean "an ugly woman", but this much is for sure: a parenthesis *absolutely never* means a quotation mark.

Comment: I might have heard/read it used in that sense once or twice, but it's far from common or widespread.  To most "Wilma" is Mrs Flintstone.  (And it actually sounds more Australian than American.)

Comment: Thank you all for you quick response. Dan Born, l am waiting for your search at the library.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, this was a 1980s reference to Wilma Flintstone of cartoon fame, but the usage didn't survive.  Check *[The Prodigal Tongue: Dispatches from the Future of English](https://books.google.com/books?id=HsSjgwMkUTYC&pg=PA125&lpg=PA125&dq=urban%20dictionary%20wilma&source=bl&ots=mz-_sfN2-R&sig=rLK2SUkWJDZpRLO8kB27Bnys9cg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAzgKahUKEwiOs4fM3MfIAhWMbT4KHdlUBio#v=onepage&q=urban%20dictionary%20wilma&f=false)* for the provenance.

Comment: Deadrat, I appreciate your sending me that reference book. But, does that mean nobody use it now?

Comment: @midomido Yes, it's the lexicographer's dilemma.  Some slang lasts and some doesn't.  This one doesn't seem to have made it into this century.